# Show that this Variation of Thomae Function is Unbounded in any subinterval of [0,1], proof outline check.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as follows:
>   $$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
> 0 & \text{for } x \in \mathbb{R}_+\setminus\mathbb{Q} \\\\
> n & \text{for } x = \frac mn \in \mathbb{Q}_+ \text{ with } (m,n) = 1
> \end{cases}$$

This is Thomae's function, and I'm asked to prove that it is unbounded in any subinterval of $[0,1]$.

Here is my plan to solve the problem:

Take any $(a,b) \subset [0,1] $. Let $x= \frac mp$ where p is a prime. Then $f(x) = p$. Because there are an infinite number of primes, $f$ is therefore unbounded on $(a,b)$

Comment: You still need to show that there is an $x$ of the form $\frac mp$ in $(a,b)$. Nitpick: There is no such $x$ where $p=5$ and $(a,b)=(0.45,0.55)$, for example. But the argument is fine as long as you can show that there are $x$s of the form $\frac mp$ for sufficiently large $p$.

Comment: The way I'd do it, to be honest, is to notice that for any $N$, there is only a finite number of $x$s where $f(x)\le N$ (Do you see why?). Since any interval contains infinitely many points, any interval must contain an $x$ (in fact, infinitely many $x$s) where $f(x)>N$. Since this works for any $N$, $f$ must be unbounded.

Comment: Yes I think I see why it's true there are a finite number of x's where $f(x) \le N$  : take $N=2$. Then there are only a finite number of $x's$, i.e.: $\frac 11$ $=1$ that satisfy the condition. But eventually, since there are infinitely many points, there is an x where $f(x)$ overtakes $N$...correct?

Comment: Yeah. Since there are infinitely many points in any $(a,b)$, and only finitely many where $f(x)\le N$, there must be infinitely many where $f(x)>N$. (Since every $x$ must be one or the other.)

Comment: Thanks for the help. For argument's sake, do you think it's possible to finish the proof the way I started it? Or is it more trouble than it's worth?

Comment: Yeah, I think it's doable. You probably need to focus on $p$ such that $\frac1p<|b-a|$ (there are infinitely many). I think that for any such $p$ there's probably exists an $x=\frac mp\in(a,b)$.

Comment: What's in the question right now isn't Thomae's function.

Comment: I submitted an edit but it makes the rest of the question wrong.

Comment: I believe this is a variation of Thomas's function.

Comment: @user3491648 Oh. Yeah. Thomae's _is_ bounded. I guess this is kinda like the reciprocal of Thomae's? In any case, what is in the question is unbounded on every interval, as our above discussion shows.

Comment: Yes Thomas's is bounded, perhaps I should delete this or mention it's a variation?

Comment: Should be fixed  now

Comment: Let $0\leq a<b\leq 1.$ Let $n\in \Bbb N.$  If $p$ is prime $p>n$ and if $p$ is  large enough then for some $q\in \Bbb N$ we will have $a<q/p<b.$ Since $q/p<b\leq 1\implies q<p$ and since $p$ is prime, we have $ f(q/p)=p>n .$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show that there are rational numbers with arbitrarily large denominators in (a,b). This is because the number of rational points in (a,b) is infinite, and the number of rational numbers with denominators less than any $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ in (a,b) is finite because it's finite in [0,1]. So by contradiction, there is a rational number in (a,b) with denominator greater than $n$. Call this rational number $x$. $f(x) > n$.

To see that there are an infinite number of rational numbers in (a,b) when $a \not = b$, just take the average of $a$ and $b$ and the average of that with $a$, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Let $0\leq a<b\leq 1.$ For $n\in \Bbb N$ let $S(n)=[0,1]\cap \{a/b: a,b\in \Bbb N\land b\leq n\}$ and let $T(n)=\{x\in \Bbb Q\cap [0,1]: f(x)\leq n\}.$ We have $T(n)\subset S(n).$

(I). If $a,a',b,b'\in \Bbb N$ with $b\leq n\geq b'$ and such that $a/b, a'/b'$ are unequal members of $S(n)$, then $0\neq |ab'-a'b|\neq 0,$ so $|ab'-ba'|\geq 1,$ so $|a/b-a'/b'|=|ab'-a'b|/|bb'|\geq 1/|bb'|\geq 1/n^2.$

(II). Given $n\in \Bbb N$ let  $n'=\max (n^2+1,\; 3( b-a)^{-1}+1).$ Let $m'=\min \{m\in \Bbb N: m'/n'\geq b\}.$ We have $m'\geq 3$ because $2/n'\leq 2(b-a)/3<b.$

We have $(m'-1)/n'< b\leq m'/n'$ and $1/n'<(b-a)/3$ so $a<(m'-2)/n'<(m'-1)/n'<b.$

But $|(m'-2)/n'-(m'-1)/n'|=1/n'<1/n^2.$ So by (I) it  is not possible for both $(m'-2)/n'$ and $(m'-1)/n'$ to belong to $S(n)$ so at least one of them does not belong to $T(n)$.

So at least one $x\in \{(m'-2)/n' , (m'-1)/n'\}$ satisfies $(x\in (a,b) \land f(x)>n).$

I wanted to give a proof that doesn't mention primes.